# JSF Primefaces - Showing another page when dialog is closed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have requirement in which I need to close the dialog after record save. Once the records is successfully saved, need to take the user some other .xhtml page. Can someone help on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just return a valid navigation outcome in the action method of the save button in dialog.

E.g.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
```

with

```
public String save() {
    // ...

    return "other.xhtml";
}
```